# better way to mark deleted entries in RDBMS

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-design

I have to keep records for entities in my RDBMS even if a user deletes some entity from the front end. Say i have a user table where each user has a unique email. Now say user with name `name1` had an email `email1`. Now that user record is deleted from the front end and someone tries to create a user with `name2` and email `email1`. This would violate the unique constraint on the `email` column but i still have to keep that record in that table, so i have a column called `status` in my table whose default value is `1`. Now i have a unique constraint on `email` and `status`. Whenever someone deletes a user i increment the status by 1. But this has problem in case where a user record with email `email1` is deleted twice. In that case i would have a 2 user records with status `2`. 
So this method fails. Another way is to move the deleted records in a different table which does not have a constraint of any sort. But using this approach i need to have an extra table for each table for which i need to keep track of deleted entries. So i find this stupid. Any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: In your application while accessing email check if status=>1 then consider it deleted

Comment: @xrcwrn yes i can do that but for that i have to a read. I want to do it without doing a read and just using the unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use timestamp column instead of number to store deleted status because time information is usually necessary too. It is known as temporal model and normally it uses two timestamps to define validity interval http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database Anchor model extends this model with special concepts: Anchor,Tier,Knot,Attribute http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_Modeling
Actually all of temporal models have many issues in regular RDBMS implementations, this issue is addressed in SQL 2012 but it is not widely implemented at the mean time and RDBMS vendors provide very different solutions a.k.a.  Change Data Capture or Flashback.

Comment: The officially correct name for the recentmost version of the SQL standard is 'SQL:2011', not 'SQL 2012'.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011 .